# Create (and persist) file from Java in Docker container

Tags: java, spring, docker

I am developing a Java Spring Boot application meant to run in a Docker container. When I run the image, I need the app to check if a file exists in a path, and to create it if does not exist. When I stop the container and start it again, the file is missing again.
How can I achieve this? Do I need to mount a volume on the host?

Comment: Upon deleting the container everything you stored in it is going to be deleted with it. Basically what starting a container is: 1.) Start the container 2.) Copy the "image" in there. 3.) Mount any given volumes in there. In your case you should probably create a folder/file and mount it in your contanier using either the `-v` command for normal docker or the `volumes:` option for `docker-compose`.

Comment: Also upon rereading: You only stopped the container, not actually deleted it? Can you confirm that? Stop the container, run `docker container list` and see if it is still there with status `stopped`. In that case no files should be deleted by docker. Maybe you started a new container over restarting the old one?

Comment: May be, I am not really comfortable with Docker so I am using just as a testing environment right now. I'll try to stop and restart it without deleting.

Comment: Okay, do so! Don't forget to use [`docker start`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/#usage) to start a stopped container, not `docker run` (which creates a new container).

Comment: Plus if you specified --rm when you started the container it will be deleted when stopped.

Comment: Remember that you do need to somewhat routinely delete containers (to change the underlying image; to change a variety of `docker run` options) and if your workflow depends on the container surviving `docker stop`/`docker start`, you're eventually going to lose that piece of data.  There's nothing wrong with a `docker build`/`docker run`/`docker rm` workflow, but it depends on storing the actual data in a volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as @Ben suggested it is working fine when I stop/start the container instead of running it.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say your Java app called `app` that saves a file in:

```
/var/lib/data
```

Then you should launch your container as follows:

```
docker volume create app-data

docker run -p 8080:8080 --mount source=app-data,target=/var/lib/data app
```

This will store all your data in a persistent volume named `app-data`

You can also bind a directory between the host machine and the container as follows:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --volume /var/lib/data:/var/lib/data app
```

This will store everything in `/var/lib/data` on the host rather than in the container. That way, the next time you start the container, it reads from there.

I typically go with the first option, as I have a name for the data I am storing, and it is not changing the "state" of the host machine (arguably still is, but very minimally). Binding a directory leaves room for error if any other process running on the host touches that directory.

See: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: This is something I don't feel like doing. I don't want those data to "leave" the container.